# HTML Frames not appearing

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a simple webpage using frames.
Currently I have file index.html with the following code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Index</title>
    <meta name="description" content="description">
    <meta name="author" content="author">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<frameset>
    <frame name="header" src="header.html">
    <frame name="sidebar" src="sidebar.html">
    <frame name="mainarea" src="home.html">
    <frame name="footer" src="footer.html">
</frameset>

</html>
```

Files header.html, sidebar.html, home.html, and footer.html all look like this:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Header</title>
  <meta name="description" content="description">
  <meta name="author" content="author">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <p>Header</p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to open the file (index.html), I get [this](http://prntscr.com/d3o7g3).

What am I doing in incorrectly? I want all 4 html files to display, not just the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `rows` and `cols` on the `frameset` element — or the browser will not know how to size the frames, and will not display them properly.

This code, for instance, would yield four quadrants:

```
<frameset cols="50%,*" rows="50%,*">
    <frame name="header" src="header.html">
    <frame name="sidebar" src="sidebar.html">
    <frame name="mainarea" src="home.html">
    <frame name="footer" src="footer.html">
</frameset>
```

Your example calls for something like this:

```
<frameset cols="100%" rows="10%,*,10%">
  <frame name="header" src="header.htm" noresize="">

  <frameset cols="20%,80%" rows="100%">
    <frame name="sidebar" src="sidebar.htm" noresize="">
    <frame name="home" src="home.htm" noresize="">
  </frameset>

  <frame name="footer" src="footer.htm" noresize="">
</frameset>
```

NB: `frameset` is not valid HTML5 as it has been deprecated. I recommend you to look into newer ways of achieving the desired effect if this is for anything non-trivial, as browsers probably won't support `frameset` forever.

Comment: Thanks! What do you think I should use instead of frameset? I need a way to "import" html from other files, so that If I change the "sidebar" file all of my pages change.

Comment: You should probably use [`iframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) which replace `frames` in HTML5.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at iframes.